# What is the the openid-config url for a token generated by Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an Azure API Management policy to validate JWT token. This token comes from our Azure Devops release pipeline. Does anyone know what the correct openid-config url is?

Here is a sample I took out from microsoft docs:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <audiences>
        <audience>25eef6e4-c905-4a07-8eb4-0d08d5df8b3f</audience>
    </audiences>
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="id" match="all">
            <value>insert claim here</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

Comment: If the solution provided below helps your problem, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `openid-config` url is independent of whether it came from devops.

**If you use Azure AD**, you can use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aad-tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration`(for v1 endpoint) as `openid-config` url. And you can also use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`(for v2 endpoint) as `openid-config` url. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests).

[image]

**But if you don't use Azure AD**, you need to find the `openid-configuration` by yourself.